# Center image using margins

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser, margin

I'm having browser compatibility issues, in Chrome and Firefox when I use margin left and right to center and reduce image. Perfect, that's what I want. Buuuuut, only in the first image, the other images do not react the same way.

And in IE and Edge not even the first works as I wanted. The images just go right.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png" class="img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope" style="margin: 0 39%;">
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope" style="margin: 0 39%;">
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope" style="margin: 0 39%;">
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eduardodallmann/pen/ZyQbyq)

Explanations of why this happens? (Yes, I know the solution is to use `Width: Percentage`. I was just curious.)

Comment: the images aren't the same widths so the margins aren't going to work the same between them. make them `block` and use `margin: auto`. you just need the left/right `margin`s to be `auto` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/rwxOPE.

Comment: Really only square images change size when using margin. Thanks @MichaelCoker

Answer (score -1):

Are you controlling the size of the images using margin?

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img1 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://sismonitor.com.br/sismonitor/images/logo.svg" class="img1 img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope">

<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="img2 img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope">

<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="img3 img-responsive center-block logo-index ng-scope">
```